# Spring compression and quick release mechanism

Tags: mechanical, robotics, springs

I'm in a group and we're designing a wheel that can inflate and decompress using springs. The purpose of the string compression/decompression is to give our tires this jumpy/bouncy like movement. There are strings connected to the top of the springs where they pull them down by turning the servo motors the strings are connected to. The only problem is that we want to release the springs fast enough for them to pop out, and we believe just turning the servo motor the other way won't be efficient. We're open to any suggestions to get this jumping motion in our wheels, so feel free to point us in a direction that would lead us to the same result if you don't have an exact solution to the compress/decompress spring idea. Feel free to include any links to articles, videos, or other projects that have this same kind of issue I can look to for a fix to my issue. Thank you for your time in advance.